# The top tags in my profile do not reflect synonym changes

Tags: support, bug, tags, profile-page, tag-synonyms

In my view there is a bug in tag synonyms in that if one is created, a user's profile and their statistics don't merge across.

As an example I have answered a few questions on the [ssrs-reports](/questions/tagged/ssrs-reports) and it is now a synonym of [reporting-services](/questions/tagged/reporting-services) but I still have the legacy tag and its statistics in my profile.

I have a few queries:

1. Are my answers no longer assigned to that tag and only show as legacy and these statistics should be on the new tag? Can this be confirmed?
2. Or do these old tags no longer exist and they should be removed from my statistics --  transferring to the new tag. Can this be confirmed and/or be implemented?

Comment: Possibly related: [Upon edit, \[img\] is replaced with \[image\]](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178440)

Comment: Thanks @DannyBeckett I appreciate your thoughts. I don't want to confuse my question with a simple tag synonym request.

Comment: Possibly relates [tag scores have not updated script did not run](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run)

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that this is just a different manifestation of the ["Tag scores have not updated; script did not run"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178114/148310) problem of the last few days.

When that problem gets resolved, the (now) synonyms should disappear from your profile and the master tags get the correct combined score.

---

**Update:**
In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177144/148310), and its comments, an example is given showing that at least *some* synonyms are not updated/replaced on the tag list.  However, [the example synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lazy-evaluation/synonyms), [lazy](/questions/tagged/lazy), was created several years ago (jul 25 '10 at 5:40). So, maybe it was missed in the early process.  It would seem to be undesirable behavior to have phantom tags in some places.

<strike>Maybe, the system *now* works as expected? When [the current tag-score bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178114/148310) is resolved, we will check to see if the OP's synonyms got merged.  If not, then this seems like a potential bug or feature request.</strike>

**Updatier:**
[Jeff has declared that this behavior is "not a bug"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90227/148310), and there is already [a feature-request of sorts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131506/148310).

Since [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178606/148310)  [keeps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135409/148310)  [coming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90227/148310)  [up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131506/148310), perhaps it's time to investigate some better way of automatically merging tags.  Perhaps it should happen automatically within, say, a week of a synonym being approved, but the change should be made as a *Community* edit to the questions, so that it can be reversed in those [(¿extremely rare?) cases where a synonym needs to be undone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btag-synonyms%5D%20title:reverse).

Comment: The behavior is completely by-design (there's no bug, and there is already a [feature request to auto-merge synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131506)). Tags don't get auto-merged *just* because a synonym is created so they can be unmerged easily if the synonym was wrong. A moderator will have to conduct a merge for the tag scores to be combined.

Comment: Okay, @animuson, that kills one theory; thanks.