# Retagging deleted questions should not affect tag question counts

Tags: bug, tags, moderators

We have 492 deleted questions tagged [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged). Yes, deleted questions have tags too! They just don't count for the number of questions tagged as such.

Moderators *can* search for and edit deleted questions and this doesn't trash the homepage, so I started doing just that. Most of those are "identify-this-game" or "game-rec" anyway. There *is* one side effect however: every time I apply a tag to a deleted question, the tag counters are updated as if it was a regular question. As a result now [/tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags?page=29&tab=name) says there's a bunch of questions tagged "identify-this-game" when they're really only two questions (both awaiting certain deletion.)

I suppose tag counts are updated hourly/daily/weekly/full moonly/manually/every Saturday in Iceland, so eventually this will fix itself. This is still a (really really minor, really really petty, "why the hell are you doing this in the first place?!") problem.

Comment: Your gravatar will haunt my nightmares

Comment: @BenBrocka meow. *(Excellent.)*

Comment: +1 for "full moonly"

Comment: Doctor, it hurts when I do this... (are y'all bored over there on Gaming? Sounds like you could use some, ahem, *game recommendations*...)

Comment: @Shog9 *silent stare* *(The curse of [tag:untagged] must be lifted from our sacred lands!)*

Comment: For reference there are 14K+ deleted questions on SO tagged [tag:untagged]... I cannot imagine a scenario that would make me want to tag these.

Comment: @Shog9 prrrr. *(#firstworldproblems. Okay okay I'll elaborate. I just want to look at accurate numbers/the full picture when discussed question categories outright banned from the site.)*

Comment: (There might be something funny going on with tag scores these days, there's been a few reports [like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178606/the-top-tags-in-my-profile-do-not-reflect-synonym-changes).)